# Что происходит, когда в БД накапливается более 100+млн записей?

Tags: mysql

Всем привет. Стало интересно, а что происходит, когда в БД (MySQL) накапливается более 100+млн записей? Они как-либо архивируются/как происходит общение с базой? Или весь вопрос в покупке более мощных серверов?

Comment: всё зависит от того, нужны ли вам эти данные для статистики или не нужны. Можно сделать, например, партиционирование https://habrahabr.ru/post/66151/

Comment: `Или весь вопрос в покупке более мощных серверов?` Нет. Вот например в VK - не было мощных серверов до недавнего времени(ну кроме распределителей). Секрет в том, что одна БД пилится на несколько БД - и разносится по разным серверам, их может быть хоть тысячи. Затем в коде подключаются только к нужным базам и выбирают только из них. Это называется шардинг и масштабирование. Но вообще 100М не предел, на одном сервере, но только не для `MySQL` - большинство других современных СУБД имеют механизмы для работы с таким.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр а какие СУБД на данный момент самые адекватные? postgre?

Comment: @Alexxosip зависит от того, что вы хотите делать с этими 100млн записями: я больше намекаю на NoSQL решения, например tarantool от mail.ru.  Из SQL postgre будет уже работать лучше, oracle ещё лучше. Но конечно тот-же oracle  будет работать шустро на 100 млн "аки одна БД", но на деле будет установлен на множестов серверов. Тогда как NoSQL - позволит не усложнять инфраструктуру.

Comment: @Alexxosipov спор про Postgre vs MySQL это как в 90-х спорили кто круче - боксер или каратист. Практически все зависит от самой архитектуры организации взаимодействия с БД. На том же MySQL прекрасно работают Youtube и Ad Words

Answer (score 4):

> Стало интересно, а что происходит, когда в БД (MySQL) накапливается
>   более 100+млн записей?

Это называется HighLoad и распределение нагрузки. Если брать саму суть вашего вопроса, то для сокращения времени обращения к данным (при очень большом их количестве) большие таблицы разделяются на несколько частей (шардов, сам процесс называется шардинг).

Далее реализуется логика обращения к этим шардам, т.к. держать ее в самом коде приложения не лучшее решение. Например, в VK это реализовано в виде сервисов. К нужному сервису пишется REST-запрос, сервис выполняет поиск данных по шардам и выдает результат в ответе.

Также имеет смысл использовать NoSQL-решения или распределенные базы данных (например, Cassandra от Facebook), но конкретная реализация сильно зависит от самих данных. Плюс не забываем про репликацию, бэкапы и отказоустойчивость.

Если же у вас всего один сервер и в него не влезает база, либо не справляется с нагрузкой, то:

1. Для начала вынесите БД на отдельный сервер с большим количеством оперативной памяти.
2. Если этого недостаточно, то имеет смысл отделить наиболее нагруженные таблицы и выносить их на отдельные сервера. Также можно попробовать разбить большие таблицы на несколько частей по типам данных (данные, которые запрашиваются редко и по ним не идет никакого поиска и сортировки - переносим в отдельные таблицы).
3. Снизить нагрузку на базу поможет кэширование данных. Используйте тот же Memcached. Даже один правильно настроенный кэшируюший сервер способен уменьшить нагрузку на базу в разы (конечно, при условии, что используется кэширование подходящих запросов, которые часто запрашиваются и не слишком быстро вымываются из кэша).
4. Шардинг для небольших проектов - это крайняя мера, обычно к ней прибегают, когда уже физически невозможно хранить или проводить операции над одной таблицей. Имейте ввиду, что это на порядок усложняет логику обращения к базе.

Comment: Это не называется и не имеет никакого отношения к хайлоаду. Для сокращения времени обработки обычно в первую очередь все-таки обращаются к оптимизации индексов, при определенных запросах можно добиться практически нулевой зависимости времени выполнения от размера базы данных.

Comment: @etki конечно индексы нужно использовать обязательно. что касается `добиться практически нулевой зависимости времени выполнения от размера базы данных` - на практике это не совсем так. даже при правильно настроенных индексах время запроса на таблицах в 100 записей и 100+ млн. записей будет отличаться в разы, а особенно **вставка данных** (при которой и идет пересчет всех индексов). к тому же это совершенно не поможет, если сама таблица уже не влезает на один сервер.